# Updating/patching an airgapped Ubuntu server

Tags: server

I have an airgapped Ubuntu server that I need to get patches/updates/upgrades for, any ideas how to do that when you can't remove it to bring it to an Internet connection for updates.  Cloning it, then installing the clone image to a similar box, updating the clone, and restoring that patched image back isn't an option either.  Thanks,
John

Answer (score 4):

use

```
apt-zip - Use apt with removable media
```

or

```
apt-offline - Offline APT Package manager
```

here are a couple of usage guides for apt-offline:

https://debian-administration.org/article/648/Offline_Package_Management_for_APT
https://blog.sleeplessbeastie.eu/2014/01/30/how-to-manage-packages-on-an-off-line-debian-system/